# Cambiar url con jquery

Tags: jquery, css

quiero cambiar una imagen de fondo al presionar un `input` de mi web
el CSS del elemento que quiero pulsar es:

```
.caldera-grid input[type=radio]{

  background-image:url("http://rentmovers.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/bg-form-btn-selected.png");
  background-size:cover;
}
```

y el fragmento de código usado es

```
  $('.caldera-grid input[type=radio]').on('click',function(e){
           $(this).css("background-image","http://rentmovers.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/bg-form-btn-selected-1.png");
  });
```

a parte de más código que no viene al caso y no me funciona alguna idea?

Comment: Intenta hacer `$(this).css("background-image","url(http://rentmovers.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/bg-form-btn-selected-1.png)");` a ver si jala

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que solo te falto el url():

```
$(this).css('background-image', 'url(http://rentmovers.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/bg-form-btn-selected-1.png)');
```

Mas info: http://librosweb.es/referencia/css/background-image.html